# Are enemies' full-body shields weak to electric damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

The game mentions that shields are weak to electric damage. Does this apply to full-body shields carried by Nomads and mini-bosses like Doc Mercy/Bad Maw?

Comment: It seems sort of obvious that physical shields != energy shields.

Comment: this was not obvious to me for a very long time in the game and I assume others have had this issue.

Answer (score 5):

No. The specific weakness to electricity only applies to energy shields worn by enemies, which are the equivalent of the energy shields worn/equipped by players. Enemies with energy shields weak to electricity will have a blue bar above their health, as seen in image B below.

Image A denotes a physical shield worn by a Nomad (not weak to electricity). [See this post to deal with them.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92542/how-to-deal-with-enemies-with-full-body-shields)

Image B denotes an energy shield equipped by Master Gee (weak to electricity).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, "shields" in that context means energy shields, not metal shields.